# Calendar selection mode in kendo ui

Tags: calendar, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi is there any option in kendo ui calendar for `selection mode = DayWeekMonth` like asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. At this point Kendo calender do not have some thing like that. 
All you have is these

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/calendar#configuration